# MySQL: select word from string in column

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with a column name.
In this column i have the string `name1 name2 name3`

`table1.name(name2) LIKE table2.name`

I want to get the word after the first word or after the second word and match them with a colummn of another table.
How can I do that?

Comment: "the word after the first word or after the second word"... just a random one of those two?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't understand clearly, but -

`name1 name2 name3`

```
^\w+\h+(\w+)(?:\h+(\w+))?
```

Capture group 1 matches/contains `name2`
Capture group 2 optionally matches/contains `name3`

---

Or, if you want the last of name2 or name3

```
^\w+\h+(?:\w+\h+)?(\w+)
```

Capture group 1 matches/contains `name2`
or,
Capture group 1 matches/contains  name2 `name3`

Comment: Tanks. I get an error: SELECT * FROM `ModellBeach` WHERE modell REGEXP '\w+\h+(?:\w+\h+)?(\w+)';  #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
Example for the last word:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(modell, ' ', -1) FROM ModellBeach
```